# Python: List Looping Triggering Valid Input Loop

Tags: python, list, loops, input, discord.py

In short, I'm building a Discord bot that prompts a user to input a filename that includes a valid image type. I created a list of valid image types to check the user input with. I also have a 'valid_input' loop implemented so that if no valid image type is found, an error message is sent to the user and loops back to prompt for another input. However, if a filename with a valid image type is given, because the input is looped through the list, each time the image type doesn't match, the error is sent, but then it also finds a matching type, and reads as a success.

```
imgTypeList = ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg']
validType = any(imgTypeList)
valid_input = False
while not valid_input:
    await message.channel.send('[prompt to user]')
    msg1 = await client.wait_for("message") 
    for validType in imgTypeList:
        if validType in msg1.content:
            os.rename('[path]\{}'.format(attatchment.filename),'[path]\{}'.format(msg1.content))
            await message.channel.send('[success]')
            valid_input = True
        else:
            await message.channel.send('[error]')
```

When a file name with a valid image type is given, the error message is sent twice for the two image types that doesn't match the one in the file name, and the success message is sent once. I had tried accomplishing this without the any() argument already with the same result.

I am sure there is a simple solution to this, but I am not only very new to coding, but am also very tired at the moment. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error also occurs on valid inputs because of your `for`-loop-logic.

try

```
if (any([element in msg1.content for element in imgTypeList])):
    # success
else:
    # error
```

instead of your for loop